¿Como volver a modo desarrollo un proyecto ya compilado que usa vite y tailwindcss en laravel 10?
Buenas me surgió una duda, o mas que duda problema que no logro resolver. Tengo un proyecto en laravel donde eh usado tailwindcss con vite. La cosa es que ya compilé el front ejecutando npm-run-build. Ahora quiero hacer cambios visuales, eso me lleva a esta pregunta: ¿Es necesario volver a modo producción ejecutando npm-run-dev o ya no es necesario hacer esto?, y si fuera necesario hacerlo, ¿Cómo lo hago? por que intente ejecutar ese comando y tengo este error:
Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
[Failed to load PostCSS config: Failed to load PostCSS config

Que tampoco logro dar con la solución.

npm run build lo unico que hace (aunque habria que confirmarlo mirando tu config.json) es transpilar tu codigo a un modulo js minificado... salvo que laravel haga algo que vaya en contra de todo, no tenes que volver a ningun modulo de nada. Si quedo corriendo, cancela la corrida, volvelo a correr del modo que te sirva y listo... Igual, a veces php hace cosas muy raras puedo estar totaltmente errado...

Entiendo, pense segun yo en volver a ejecutar el modo desarrollo y despues volver a compilar. Con los cambios hechos supongo que no es necesario.
